# Adding Tokens to existing Python Blockchain

Tags: python, blockchain

We have a custom blockchain written in Python and it does not have any tokens or addresses associated with it. The objective here is for us to add a set number of tokens to our existing blockchain. We understand that we don't store addresses on the blockchain but rather the wallet will create the addresses based on a few things. If anyone could direct me somewhere where I can find information on how to add tokens to our existing blockchain. Thank you in advance...